# Fabric fabfil execution model ArgumentParser

Tags: python, parameter-passing, fabric

I made some scripts that use Fabric, It does some work on multiple servers using ssh. But my scripts are like a classic python script

Here is the shape (the way they look like) : `my_script.py` with some function and a main :

```
from fabric.api import *
from a_custom_class import *

def function1():
    #do stuff
def function2():
    #do stuff

def main():
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-n', '--nolaunch', help='start the parsing', action='store_false')
    ...
    execute(function1)
    execute(function2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

So to use my script I just do `python my_script.py <my_options_for_ArgumentParser>`
This works great. But I can't manage to call it with `fab -f my_scrip.py main`.

Was I wrong to write the script like an 'usual' script ? Or there is a way to call it with `fab` without re-writting it ?

When I try `fab -f my_script.py main` it output the help from my script (so I feel I'm close to something) :

```
usage fab [-h] [-n] [-g] [-m CARTO]
```

those are my options from the scipt. But it's not displayed the same way if I try to call it the 'usual way' `python my_script.py -h`:

```
 -h, --help            show this help message and exit
 -n, --nolaunch        start the parsing
 -g, --html            generate the html
 -m CARTO, --carto CARTO  Do the carto stuff
```

Calling the real main just list the functions from my script `fab -f my_script.py __main__` and I can call any function with : `fab -f my_script.py my_function` 
But I can't figure out how to give the options value for ArgumentParser. I tried things like : `fab -f my_script.py main:<myoptions>` but without success.

Comment: That's hard to tell. Your code isn't reproducible. I can only guess that fabric "eats" arguments from command line before you get any chance to parse it...

Comment: Sorry I couldn't put the real code, it's a few thousands lines. Yes I think that's it, Fabric try to read the argument as if it was for him. I'll just stick with my classic call `python my_script.py <option>`. I might do a small Fab task that ask interactively the options and call my script afterward.

Comment: That would be nice. I tried to look at fabrics source code and it uses ``OptionParser`` from ``optparse`` package. I even tried to check whether ``OptionParser`` deletes arguments, however after while of being unsuccessful, I got bored and failed. But let me know if you did better, thanks. :)

Comment: I might do a config file and parse it in my main. and call `fab task --config=CONF.cfg` and i'll have my option in the `CONF.cfg`

Answer (score 0):

I found a way. But it's really ugly.

```
#fabfile.py
import my_script as script

def task():
    execute(script.mainbis)
```

and in my_script.py, I creat a mainbis() that overide the sys.argv and call main function :

```
#my_script.py
def mainbis():
    # ask interactively the option
    # list_option=['--What', '--the', '--user', '--said']
    list_option.insert(0,my_script.py) #we need the script name as 1st argument
    sys.argv=list_option
    main()
```

Now I can call : `fab task` and feed the option after. Do you guys think this is acceptable ?

Also, there is this env.variable in fabric :

> tasks Default: []
>
> Set by fab to the full tasks list to be executed for the currently
>   executing command. **For informational purposes only.**

Maybe I can load my argument in there when I call `fab task --tasks=<my_options>`
But once again, I feel like it's not the proper way to do it